# what is a list pointer?is it possible to have an example of what a list pointer looks like?

Tags: list, pointers, graph, representation

i am actually working on graphs representation, that is how do we represent a graph with a number of nodes and edges?

Comment: sorry what language and environment are we talking here

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list pointer by pointing to a first element that points to the second element, and so on. Well, if I understand well your question.
In object oriented, you make a class containing whatever you want and a method 'getNext()' that contains an instance of the same class, or null if it's the last element.
In C, you can make a 'struct'